# Lock branch and alert developers that I am checking-in

Tags: git, azure-devops, team-explorer

We have recently started using: "New Pull Request" from Visual Studio 2017 Team Explorer -> Git.

One common issue is that once a developer creates "New Pull Request", often simultaneous PUSH to the main branch gives conflicts. When the Pull Request browser window opens, either the .csproj is conflicting or any other. It shows error: "Merge failed because of conflict".

How can we deal with this issue? Is there any way to lock Push if any Pull request is already in progress? Anyway to alert all developers that I am about to Push?

Comment: I think creating a process around this is flat out dumb.  You may want to improve your branch / merging processes first. Lots of good info here:  https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/  Also, what are the conflicts you are getting on the .csproj file?  You could just be storing things there that don't need to be there (I'm thinking of local web server settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set branch policies or local the main branch.

#### Option 1: set [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies)

You can add branch policies for the main branch (base branch when creating a PR), so that new changes to the main branch can only be added by pull request.

#### Option 2: [Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/lock-branches) the main branch

You can lock/unlock the branch manually in the web page:

[image]

Or you can use [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/refs#lock-a-branch) to lock/unlock the branch automatically:

Such as use web hooks to lock and unlock the branch automatically. When **Pull request created** event is triggered, local the branch. When **Code pushed** event is triggered, unlock the branch.